# Can't find 'Master Detail Forms App' option in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm following a tutorial online on Xamarin Forms, and I was told to select a 'master detail forms app'. The unfortunate thing is, is that I can't find this option for a 'master detail forms' app in the tab below:

[image]

Maybe I haven't installed something?

Thanks,

Comment: Flyout is probably what they're referring to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't find 'Detail Forms App' option in Xamarin Forms?

For Visual Studio 2019, the old Detail Forms template has been [replaced with flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#xamarin) template, if you do want to make Detail app and contains uwp platform, please try make Xamarin app with Visual Studio 2017.